# How to launch statistics plugin in WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've installed [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509) to WebStorm, but I can't seem to find a way to actually launch it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is available **for IntelliJ IDEA only** and not compatible with any other products like WebStorm/PhpStorm etc (possibly because it may require Java-specific functionality that other IDEs do not provide).

You can see all WebStorm-compatible plugins if you switch to WebStorm tab (e.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?webStorm).

You can also see (and install) such plugins directly in WebStorm -- `Settings/Preferences | Plugins --> Browse repositories...`